# map polar coordinates to webgl shader uv

Tags: three.js, webgl

In my WebGL shader I would like to map the U value of my texture based on the output of a function (atan) whose range is [0,2*PI). But the range of U (as expected by texture2D) is [0,1]. So I'm trying to map an open interval to a closed interval.

This shows the problem:
[image]
The horizontal red gradient is the U axis and goes from Red=1 to Red=0 as my atan goes from 0 to 2*PI. But atan treats 2*PI as zero so there is a red band on the right after the gradient has gone black. (There are red bands on the top and bottom too, but that is a similar problem having to do with the V value, which I'm ignoring for the purposes of this question).

See this image using three.js' ability to show the vertices:
[image]

You can see how the right-most vertices (U=1) are red corresponding again to atan=0 instead of 2*PI.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? I can't force atan to return a 2*PI. I don't want to tile the texture. Can I map the U value to an open interval somehow?

I keep thinking there must be an easy solution but have tried every fix I can think of.

Here is my vertex shader:

```
void main()
{

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

    // convert from uv to polar coords
    vec2 tempuv = uv;
    theta = (1.0-tempuv[1]) * PI;
    phi = PI * 2.0 * tempuv[0];

    // convert polar to cartesian. Theta is polar, phi is azimuth.
    x = sin(theta)*cos(phi);
    y = sin(theta)*sin(phi);
    z = cos(theta);

    // and convert back again to demonstrate problem.
    // problem: the phi above is [0,2*PI]. this phi is [0,2*PI)
    phi = atan2(y, x);
    if (phi < 0.0) {
        phi = phi + PI*2.0; 
    }
    if (phi > (2.0 * PI)) { // allow 2PI since we gen uv over [0,1]
        phi = phi - 2.0 * PI;
    }
    theta = acos(z);

    // now get uv in new chart.
    float newv = 1.0 - theta/PI;
    float newu = phi/(2.0 * PI);
    vec2 newuv = vec2(newu, newv);
    vUv = newuv;
}
```

Here is my fragment shader:

```
void main() {
    vec2 uv = vUv;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0- uv[0],0.,0.,1.);
}
```

Comment: divide by 2 * PI, and write a function which call atan and when atan(x) > `2PI - precision`, you return 1.

Comment: That won't work because the next 'u' less than 1.0 corresponds to the next vertex and we don't want to mess with that color.

Comment: replace `phi = PI * 2.0 * tempuv[0]` with `phi = PI * 2.0 * tempuv[0] *0.9999999;`, with that you won't reach `2*PI`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of looking at the problem is as you mentioned, 1 comes 0 at the edge. But another way of looking at it is if you changed uv to go from 0 to 2 instead of 0 to 1 and you then used `fract(uv)` you'd get the same problem several times over because you're effectively sampling a function and each point can only choose 1 color whereas to map it correctly you'd need some how have each point magically pick 2 colors for the vertices that need to be one color for interpolating to the left and another for interpolating to the right.

Example with `fract(uv * 2.)`

```js
var vs = `
#define PI radians(180.)

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    gl_Position = position;

    // convert from uv to polar coords
    vec2 tempuv = fract(texcoord * 2.);

    float theta = (1.0-tempuv[1]) * PI;
    float phi = PI * 2.0 * tempuv[0];

    // convert polar to cartesian. Theta is polar, phi is azimuth.
    float x = sin(theta)*cos(phi);
    float y = sin(theta)*sin(phi);
    float z = cos(theta);

    // and convert back again to demonstrate problem.
    // problem: the phi above is [0,2*PI]. this phi is [0,2*PI)
    phi = atan(y, x);
    if (phi < 0.0) {
        phi = phi + PI * 2.0; 
    }
    if (phi > (2.0 * PI)) { // allow 2PI since we gen uv over [0,1]
        phi = phi - 2.0 * PI;
    }
    theta = acos(z);

    // now get uv in new chart.
    float newv = 1.0 - theta/PI;
    float newu = phi/(2.0 * PI);
    vec2 newuv = vec2(newu, newv);
    vUv = newuv;
}
`;

var fs = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
    vec2 uv = vUv;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0- uv[0],0.,0.,1.);
}
`;

var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var m4 = twgl.m4;
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
var bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createPlaneBufferInfo(
  gl, 2, 2, 20, 20, m4.rotationX(Math.PI * .5));

twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    
gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Moving the code to the fragment shader effectively solves it.

Example with code moved to fragment shader

```js
var vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    gl_Position = position;
    vUv = texcoord;
}
`;

var fs = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 vUv;

#define PI radians(180.)

void main() {

    // convert from uv to polar coords
    vec2 tempuv = vUv;

    float theta = (1.0-tempuv[1]) * PI;
    float phi = PI * 2.0 * tempuv[0];

    // convert polar to cartesian. Theta is polar, phi is azimuth.
    float x = sin(theta)*cos(phi);
    float y = sin(theta)*sin(phi);
    float z = cos(theta);

    // and convert back again to demonstrate problem.
    // problem: the phi above is [0,2*PI]. this phi is [0,2*PI)
    phi = atan(y, x);
    if (phi < 0.0) {
        phi = phi + PI * 2.0; 
    }
    if (phi > (2.0 * PI)) { // allow 2PI since we gen uv over [0,1]
        phi = phi - 2.0 * PI;
    }
    theta = acos(z);

    // now get uv in new chart.
    float newv = 1.0 - theta/PI;
    float newu = phi/(2.0 * PI);
    vec2 newuv = vec2(newu, newv);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0- newuv[0],0.,0.,1.);
}
`;

var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var m4 = twgl.m4;
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
var bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createPlaneBufferInfo(
  gl, 2, 2, 20, 20, m4.rotationX(Math.PI * .5));

twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    
gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Keeping it a vertex shader one solution is just to fudge the numbers so they're between say 0.00005 and 0.99995.

```js
var vs = `
#define PI radians(180.)

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    gl_Position = position;

    // convert from uv to polar coords
    vec2 tempuv = texcoord * 0.9999 + 0.00005;

    float theta = (1.0-tempuv[1]) * PI;
    float phi = PI * 2.0 * tempuv[0];

    // convert polar to cartesian. Theta is polar, phi is azimuth.
    float x = sin(theta)*cos(phi);
    float y = sin(theta)*sin(phi);
    float z = cos(theta);

    // and convert back again to demonstrate problem.
    // problem: the phi above is [0,2*PI]. this phi is [0,2*PI)
    phi = atan(y, x);
    if (phi < 0.0) {
        phi = phi + PI * 2.0; 
    }
    if (phi > (2.0 * PI)) { // allow 2PI since we gen uv over [0,1]
        phi = phi - 2.0 * PI;
    }
    theta = acos(z);

    // now get uv in new chart.
    float newv = 1.0 - theta/PI;
    float newu = phi/(2.0 * PI);
    vec2 newuv = vec2(newu, newv);
    vUv = newuv;
}
`;

var fs = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
    vec2 uv = vUv;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0- uv[0],0.,0.,1.);
}
`;

var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var m4 = twgl.m4;
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
var bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createPlaneBufferInfo(
  gl, 2, 2, 20, 20, m4.rotationX(Math.PI * .5));

twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    
gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

This only works though because the texcoords go from 0 to 1. If they went from zero to > 1 (or less than 0) you'd run into the same problem as above that certain vertices need more than 1 color. You'd basically need to use the fragment shader solution

Comment: Thank you so much! Of course, that is obvious: move the code to the fragment shader. Should have thought of that earlier.